# React - Ordering data coming from FireBase

Tags: hook

The following component connects to a FireBase collection, called `FlashCards`, gets the data using `get()` function and then save them inside the **cards** using the `setCards`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const List = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .get()
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <li key={card.id}>
            {card.customId}
            {card.originalText}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Each document in the collection FlashCards has a field called **customId**.
I want to order my data by that customId.

For this I tried the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .get()
        .orderBy('customId');
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

orderBy is not a function

How can I order my data by customId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to switch “orderBy” and “get”

Comment: Cool. That did the trick. I didn't know that the order is important. Thanks